# Strings loaded from JSON file and dynamic Image creation in QML/QtQuick

Tags: json, qt, qml, qt-quick

I am writing a currency converter for SailfishOS, and have to display the currency symbols like £, $, €. Since RTL languages messes around with my editor (and because I tried to remedy the error), they are UTF-8 encoded. All is fine, except for some currencies (GBP, HUF, NOK, AUD, CAD, HKD, IDR, ILS, KRW, MYR, NZD and maybe more). When using them in the UI, they completely corrupt the graphics; slows down the app, hides elements and some times makes the backgound flash red, cyan, green.

I tried using `encodeURIComponent` and it has had some effect; now the app doesn't completely freeze, but can't exactly be shipped ;)

Edit 1 9/17-2019: Apparently it is not the currency *symbols* that causes the error, but rather the currency *names*, which leaves me even more befuddled. How can "Australian Dollar" or "New Israeli Shekel" cause the graphics to mess all up?

Edit 2 9/17-2019: It turned out to be, what I think was, a combination of some long currency names and some png files that were dynamically changed, that caused memory corruption due to missing garbage collection. I added a `gc()` before changing each image, and I made sure to truncate longer currency names.

What led me to this was a post in the [Qt wiki](https://forum.qt.io/topic/52203/help-windows-qml-image-corruption-crash-problem/2) where a program showed similar symptoms.

Examples from `currencies.json`:

```
   "CNY": {
      "symbol": "\u00a5", // This is OK
      "num": 156,
      "name": "Chinese Yuan"
   },
   "DKK": {
      "symbol": "\u006b\u0072", // This is OK
      "num": 208,
      "name": "Danish Krone"
   },
   "EUR": {
      "symbol": "\u20AC", // This is OK
      "num": 978,
      "name": "Euro"
   },
   {
   "AUD": {
       "symbol": "\u0024", // This breaks it
       "num": 36,
       "name": "Australian Dollar"
   },
   "IDR": {
       "symbol": "\u0052\u0070", // This breaks it
       "num": 360,
       "name": "Indonesian Rupiah"
   },
   "ILS": {
       "symbol": "\u20aa", // This breaks it
       "num": 376,
       "name": "New Israeli Shekel"
   },
   "NOK": { 
       "symbol": "\u006b\u0072", // This breaks it
       "num": 578,
       "name": "Norwegian Krone"
   },
  "TRY": {
     "symbol": "\u20a4", // This is OK
     "num": 949,
     "name": "Turkish Lira"
  },
  "USD": {
     "symbol": "\u0024", // This breaks it
     "num": 840,
     "name": "US Dollar"
  },
   }
```

I have tried various ways of using the symbol in the UI; all of them boils down to something like this:

```
   ListModel {
       id: currencyModel

       var allCurrencies = Currencies.all // loaded from currencies.json

       for(var currency in allCurrencies) {
           allCurrencies[currency].symbol = encodeURIComponent(allCurrencies[currency].symbol)
           append(allCurrencies[currency])
       }
   }
```

Using it in the UI:

```
    Label {
        text: decodeURIComponent(currency.symbol)
    }
```

I'm sure there is something I have overlooked, but I can't figure out what. Or maybe it has nothing to do with unicode..?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the OS or its Qt version. Have you checked any relevant bug trackers? Anyway, as a work-around solution (since you seem to be under some time pressure) I suggest using images for the symbols. Either pre-generate them to resources, or perhaps render them at run-time, if doing that doesn't screw everything up.

Comment: Hmm. That could be the reason. SailfishOS is still behind and currently on 5.6. They're still not sure when to upgrade. Now I have some reading to do ;) https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-9495?jql=text~%22utf-8%22